# maintaing backup log sequence after executing BACKUP DATABASE databasename command manually

Tags: sql-server, backup

I am new to database admin role and I have to configure backups for a new client.

I want an advice on how to handle below scenario.
I want to configure a weekly full backup along with incremental transaction log backups running frequently. Lets say I do full backup every Sunday and incremental transaction log backup every 30 minutes and I get

> TL1--> TL2--> TL3-->TL4--> {diskspace full auto backup could not complete successfully have to run backup DB command to finish the backup manually after freeing diskspace}
> -->TL6-->TL..

My problem and question  here are that

1. Is there any way I can execute the backup command without breaking my auto backup chain of incremental logs.
   I am thinking to update the column `backup_finish_date`
   of `msdb.dbo.backupset` with the time I execute the backup command, is it a viable option?
2. Is supposed in my scenario a break did occur in my log backup chain , how can I restore normal flow

Comment: if a backup failed, you don't have to do a new backup manually? just wait for the next automatic run. Full backups won't break the chain either

Comment: Having said that, you *want to* break the chain, because otherwise you would need to restore millions of log records to be able to get to a point in time. It's only useful to use `COPY_ONLY` if you are doing an *extra* full backup. If you only have a single full backup job then you can restore that, and work forwards from the log backups.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the COPY_ONLY option, the new backup does not interrupt (or otherwise take part in) your normal backup chain.

Answer (score 0):

> Is supposed in my scenario a break did occur in my log backup chain ,
> how can I restore normal flow

Differential backup let you jump over gaps in log backup chain.